# How is EXP generated for each weapon?

Tags: character-creation, en-garde

In examining the rules of En Garde! listed [here](http://patriot.net/~aquazoo/eg/eg_rules/eg_RlzFrm.html) and I've developed a certain amount of confusion over the weapon expertise mechanic.

The initial character creation has the rule for generating EXP as rolling 3d6. This is great, but that only gives me one number for EXP. A later section indicates that EXP is trained on individual weapons and so it must be tracked separately.

Is the initial EXP roll the baseline for all of the weapons? Or is it specific to one weapon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initial EXP counts for all your weapons.

When you train or gain EXP with a certain weapon your EXP with only that weapon increases.

In dueling:

> The winner of a duel increases his expertise with the *dueling weapon* by one.
>   A surviving loser of a duel receives credit for one practice session.

(My emphasis)

In practice:

> Characters may practice to improve their fencing ability. For every
>   four weeks of practice (not necessarily consecutive) a player raises
>   his Exp by 1 *for that weapon*.